# find out identifer name and typeid of the object or variable in C++?

Tags: c++, class, typeid, typeinfo

I've started learnig C++ (year ago) mostly because it's univerzal language IMO, and beacause almost everything is possible.
but one thing isn't so:
for example we are writing some code inside an object(class) and we need to find out it's name somehow:

```
class Test
{
public: const char* getMyIdentiferName()
          {
                // what now??
          }
};
```

well the best option is to use 'this' keywod but that wouldn't help cos 'this' cant return name?

```
Test thatsMyName;
const char* = thtsMyName.getMyIdentiferName(); //return string "thatsMyName" how?
```

how do we get 'thatsMyName' string in in some generic function or even template??

ANOTHER EXAMPLE:(please answer this too)

how do we get typeid of some class?

```
class MyType
{
public: type_info getType()
     {
          return typeid(this); //that wont work of course :)
     {
};
```

this looks funny but if any of you have some idea on how to achive similar task...

thanks alot.

EDIT: OK, everybodey say it's impossible to get the name of an object, I found out how to get the name:

```
class Test
{
    public: string getObjectName()
    {
        string arg = typeid(*this).name();
        arg.erase(arg.begin(), arg.begin() + 5);
        arg.erase(0,1);
        return arg;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    Test thisIsMyName;
    cout << thisIsMyName.getObjectName() << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Big thanks to Fiktik answering my second example who found the way oon how to get the type_info of the object!

Comment: `return typeid(this);` should work. Why do you say it won't work? You should also consider `return typeid(*this);`

Comment: oh thanks, and what will be the return type of that function?

Comment: A huge amount, probably the majority, of objects do not have names.

Comment: @codekiddy, the return type is `const type_info&`. See Fiktik's answer.

Comment: @Aaron McDaid and to what type to assign the return object, I'm getting error while assigning to type_info object,, even if it's const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you are asking is not possible. At least not directly.

You could create a macro for variable declaration that would register its name somewhere, something like this:

```
#define CREATE_VARIABLE(type, name) registerVariable<type>(#name); type name
```

but this is quite cumbersome and cannot be used everywhere. Why would you even want to have this functionality?

The second thing should work with only little adjustments:

```
class MyType
{
public:
    const type_info& getType()
    {
        return typeid(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your second example returns a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @larsmans, apparently `typeid` returns "a reference to std::type_info object, which exists until the end of the program". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid Therefore this is safe. I only just discovered this a few minutes ago, so check for yourself :-)

Comment: As far as I [know](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), typeid operator already returns a reference to a type_info object with global storage, so this code should be fine (except const-correctness, which I'll fix now)

Comment: I'm receiving this : "type_info::type_info(const type_info &_Rhs)" (declared at line 72 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\typeinfo") is inaccessible

Comment: @codekiddy didn't you forget the `&` before `getType()`? Because I'd imagine that would be the error in that case.

Comment: HEY, that work!  MyType ss;
 const type_info& x = ss.getType();
 if(typeid(x.name()) == typeid(int))

Comment: please also se my edit on my post how to get identifer name. hah we own it :D

Comment: @codekiddy Glad you like it :) Two points though: 1. typeid(foobar).name() can return different things with different compilers. It is always a nice name of the type, but the formatting and other small things can differ. 2. The code `thisIsMyName.getObjectName()` in your edit will most likely return "Test", not "thisIsMyName". Thats why everybody was saying its impossible to get thisIsMyName - its just a name of the variable. Test on the other hand is a type and can be obtained.

Answer (score 2):

What would you need the *variable* name for? What you're trying to do is impossible; inside an classes' methods, the name of the variable used for accessing an object isn't known.

Consider this example:

```
Test * myTest = new Test();
Test * myTest2 = myTest;
const char* identifier = myTest2->getMyIdentifierName();
```

What should `getMyIdentifierName()` return? "myTest"? "myTest2"? Nothing at all, since the object was allocated dynamically, and therefore no variable can really claim to "hold" the object?

If you just want to know the variable name which you are *currently using* for referring to an object, why not just use a string literal for it and pass it wherever you need it? But that doesn't seem to make sense in any real-world application.

If you need a name (i.e., a unique identifier) for an object at runtime, you'll best give the class a member `name` and initialize that with whatever you need.

Comment: thanks, Acctualy I don't know why would I need tha name (in first example), it looks tha's impossible, BUT another one example in my question must be possible somehow. I'm asking this cos of learning purposes.

Comment: In your example the Test object doesn't have any name at all. myTest and myTest2 are names of the pointers to this instance.

Comment: @visitor: exactly my point. object "name" in terms of variable name makes no sense in C++

Answer (score 2):

Getting the "identifier name" of an object won't work, since there is no unique identifier for an object (other than it's address, to be gotten with `&`). An unlimited number of references/pointers can designate the same object; at the same time, the language allows objects to be reached by other means than identifiers (`v[0]` where `v` is a vector is an object, but not an identifier). This is the case in all programming languages that I know, and I know a dozen of them.

As for your second question, you can return a reference to an `std::type_info`.

```
struct Test
{
    // pretty useless method
    std::type_info const &type() const { return typeid(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    Test a;
    std::cout << a.type().name() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why is `type_info` not copyable? Is there any workaround? Could we allocated it on the heap and pass around `unique_ptr` or `auto_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: To answer my own comment, I get the impression from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) that we could safely return a pointer to type_info. "It returns a reference to std::type_info object, which exists until the end of the program[1]"

Comment: You can return a reference or a pointer to a `std::type_info`.  If you have access to C++11, you could also return a `std::type_index` (which is a wrapper for `std::type_info const*`).

Comment: You sayd "Getting the "identifier name" of an object won't work" please see my edit on my post. now only question left is to get the type.

Comment: @codekiddy: I don't get your update. What's it supposed to do? `type_info::name` gives you a readable and unique name for a type.

Comment: it return identifer's name as a string. while Fiktik's answer return's typeid which can be used to compare type's. thanks alot fo your help larsmans!